# J2me -- Executing system codes

Tags: java-me, system, nokia-s40, imei

Is there a way to execute system codes such as *#06#(to get IMEI) in J2me?

Comment: did you try doing it as a PlatformRequest?  `tel:*#06#`

Comment: yes i did.But it didn't help.Any other ideas?